# can't install fixparts on centos 6.8 liveDVD

Tags: centos, dual-boot, gpt

I can't install fixparts on centos 6.8 liveDVD it gives me this error:

> Requires libc.so.6(glibc_2.14)(64bit)

How I can solve this, please? All I want is just run Fixparts to remove old GPT table strays so I can see the Windows and other partitions during installation, Also please if anyone know a method to do that using Windows 7, then please share it.